# Git/Github not seeing file renames

Tags: git, github

I have refactored a java class which involves changing the file name and the contents i.e. from

`public class CloudSealUserDetails ... in CloudSealUserDetails.java` to

`public class CloudsealUserDetails ... in CloudsealUserDetails.java` (note the case change from CloudSeal to Cloudseal)

When I run git status is shows that the contents of `CloudSealUserDetails` has changed and commits this but this is not the change that I made. Now if I look on my local file system I see a file called `CloudsealUserDetails` but in github i see `CloudSealUserDetails` and git pull/git status repots "Already up-to-date."

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug (feature?) that Git won’t see differences in case – it’s often easier to rename it to something completely different, create a commit, then change it back again.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that, do you know if I need to push the intermediate changes to github or is a local commit sufficient e.g. 

mv file fileTmp
git commit
mv fileTmp File
git commit
git push

Comment: I’m pretty sure I did it last week with just local commits without push.